# UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to listen to multicast group in C# winRT

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, multicast

I want to listen to a multicast group 239.192.168.22 on the port 50000 in my winRT app using Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket. Here my code snippet :

```
class UdpSocketAnstraction : IDisposable
{
    DatagramSocket socket;

    public UdpSocketAnstraction()
    {
        this.socket = new DatagramSocket();
        this.socket.MessageReceived += socket_MessageReceived;
    }

    public async Task Open()
    {
        await this.socket.BindServiceNameAsync("50000");
        this.socket.JoinMulticastGroup(new HostName("239.192.168.22"));
    }
}
```

JoinMulticastGroup throws a UnauthorizedAccessException with no explanations why.

I don't know if a make a bad usage of this socket or if I have to allow something on my windows, or something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the "Internet (Client & Server)" capability in Package.appxmanifest file. Double-click it and go the Declarations tab.